# Can't run viber on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, libstdc++, viber

Form few hours can't run viber on my new CentOS 7. I didn't find package from "Application Installer", so I downloaded it from official website. So I install it with:

```
rpm -Uvh viber.rpm
```

So I have viber icon in my applications but when click it, viber don't start.

I reed many similar problems, so install **libstdc++**, but didn't help.

I tried [this tips](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/nux-dextop-x86_64/viber-4.2.2.6-8.el7.nux.x86_64.rpm.html?fbclid=IwAR3B7Lvdut_MnZdM_kcTpB_1yPxuJI6iJpp1UYnwD6fp8rRAawuclaQilwM) but they didn't help too

```
[root@localhost viber]# cd /opt/viber/
[root@localhost viber]# ./Viber
./Viber: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./Viber)
./Viber: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./Viber)
./Viber: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /opt/viber/lib/libQt5Location.so.5)
./Viber: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /opt/viber/lib/libicui18n.so.52)
./Viber: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /opt/viber/lib/libicuuc.so.52)
./Viber: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /opt/viber/lib/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5)
./Viber: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /opt/viber/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5)
./Viber: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /opt/viber/lib/libQt5Core.so.5)
```

**EDIT (SOLVED):**

```
Removed:
  viber.x86_64 0:7.0.0.1035-2                                                                                                 

Complete!
[root@localhost viber]# yum install flatpak
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.netix.net
 * epel: mirror.neostrada.nl
 * extras: mirrors.netix.net
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: mirrors.netix.net
Package flatpak-0.8.8-4.el7_5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@localhost viber]# yum install flatpak ^Catpak install --from https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/com.viber.Viber.flatpakref
[root@localhost viber]# flatpak install --from https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/com.viber.Viber.flatpakref
This application depends on runtimes from:
  https://dl.flathub.org/repo/
Configure this as new remote 'flathub' [y/n]: y
Installing: com.viber.Viber/x86_64/stable
Required runtime for com.viber.Viber/x86_64/stable (org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/18.08) is not installed, searching...
Found in remote flathub, do you want to install it? [y/n]: y
Installing: org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/18.08 from flathub

8 delta parts, 76 loose fetched; 174244 KiB transferred in 24 seconds                                                         
Installing: org.freedesktop.Platform.Locale/x86_64/18.08 from flathub

6 metadata, 1 content objects fetched; 18 KiB transferred in 0 seconds                                                        
Installing: org.freedesktop.Platform.html5-codecs/x86_64/18.08 from flathub

1 delta parts, 3 loose fetched; 2455 KiB transferred in 1 seconds                                                             
Installing: com.viber.Viber/x86_64/stable from flathub

2 delta parts, 4 loose fetched; 8868 KiB transferred in 2 seconds
```

I don't know why and how, but this way working normal...

Comment: Thanks for providing the flatpack way to install. Really useful.